# Linear Classification - Decision Boundary

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

Currently, I'm trying to adapt my linear classification implementation to be able to classify multiple classes.
The objective is to minimize
$$ 
\arg\min\limits_{\mathbf{\Theta}} \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\Theta} - \mathbf{Y}\|_2^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2}\|\mathbf{\Theta}\|_2^2
$$
where $\mathbf{X} = [\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_n]^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ is the feature matrix, $\mathbf{\Theta} = [\mathbf{\theta}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{\theta}_k]\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$ is the matrix of parameter vectors that we want to estimate and $\mathbf{Y} = [\mathbf{y}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{y}_n]^T\in\{0,1\}^{n \times k}$ is the matrix of one-hot encoded class labels. Note: $n$ is the number of examples, $d$ the feature space dimension, i.e. $\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{\theta}_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$, and $k$ the number of classes.

So far so good. We can minimize this problem by the closed form solution or iterative methods as (stochastic) gradient descent, which all work just fine.

Suppose the class labels are $\{1,\ldots,k\}$, then the classification of an example $\mathbf{x}$ is done by choosing the corresponding class to the largest value in $\mathbf{\Theta}^T \mathbf{x}$, i.e. $\arg\max\limits_i [\mathbf{\Theta}^T \mathbf{x}]_i$

**Edit**

In order to understand my problem, consider the following **example**:
In the binary classification case, i.e. $k=2$, where the matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ could be written as a vector $\mathbf{y}\in\{0,1\}^n$ and $\mathbf{\Theta}$ could be written as a vector $\mathbf{\theta}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ as well, we have the objective
$$ 
\arg\min\limits_{\mathbf{\theta}} \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\theta} - \mathbf{y}\|_2^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2}\|\mathbf{\theta}\|_2^2
$$
and we can compute the decision boundary as:
$$
\mathbf{\theta}^T\mathbf{x} = 0, \quad \mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d
$$
Therefore, with $d=2$ we have the decision boundary as
$$
\mathbf{\theta}^T\mathbf{x} = 0
\quad 
\Leftrightarrow 
x_2 = -\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}x_1
$$
If we use the feature map $\phi(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}) = [1, \mathbf{x}]^T$ and $\mathbf{\theta}=[\theta_0, \theta_1, \theta_2]^T\in\mathbb{R}^3$ we are able to separate the classes with an affine decision boundary, i.e. $x_2 = ax_1 + b$, instead of $x_2 = ax_1$, we get
$$
\mathbf{\theta}^T\mathbf{\tilde{x}} = \theta_0 + \theta_1x_1 + \theta_2x_2 = 0
\quad 
\Leftrightarrow 
x_2 = -\frac{\theta_0 + \theta_1x_1}{\theta_2}
$$
This works just fine.

Here is the **problem** I have:
When I'm using one-hot encoding with $k=2$, i.e. $\mathbf{Y}\in\{0,1\}^{n \times 2}$ and the feature map $\phi(\mathbf{\tilde{x}}) = [1, \mathbf{x}]^T\in\mathbb{R}^3$, my objective function is the one at the top of this post. 
Then I have two boundaries:
$$
\mathbf{\theta}_1^T\mathbf{\tilde{x}} = 0 
\quad 
\mathbf{\theta}_2^T\mathbf{\tilde{x}} = 0
$$
sice the vector $\mathbf{\theta}$ is a matrix $\mathbf{\Theta} = [\mathbf{\theta}_1, \mathbf{\theta}_2]\in\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 2}$.
My understanding is that both should lie on top of each other. But the don't, as you can see in this example plot: [calculated decision boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOMoi.png)

Here is a visualization of how the classifier classifies points that are drawn uniformly, by plotting them in different colors according to the classification: [visualization of classifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmsWS.png) which works better but not fine I guess?

So my **question** is: 
How can I compute the decision boundary with one-hot encoding? What am I doing wrong?

I'd appreciate any help/hint! (:

**Additional Edit:**
When I use the encoding $\mathbf{y} \in \{-1,1\}^n$ I can easily calculate the decision boundary as specified above. Here you can see the same plots as before with said encoding instead of one-hot-encoding: [calculated decision boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uul62.png) and [visualization of classifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfyFO.png).

So, what's wrong with one-hot-encoding?

Comment: Okay, you wrote down a general expression for $d$ dimensions and $k$ classes.  Please lets look at your example with $d=2$ and $k=2$.  What does your cost function reduce to?  What exactly is the data you are plotting?  Is it linearly separable?  How did you find the decision boundary?

Comment: I just edited my post @mjw - the data shown in the example plots is linearly separable. I explicitly wrote down how I find the decision boundary in the binary case with and without one-hot encoding above. The problem is they don't yield in the same result. Why is that?

Comment: Are the red points and blue points feature vectors for two different classes?  If so, does not look like they are linearly separable.

Comment: It looks like the second term in your objective function is for "regularization".  What is the value of $\lambda$ you are using?  What happens when $\lambda=0$ (no regularization)?

Comment: The regularization term doesn't affect my decision boundary plot. I tried different values in $[0,1)$

Comment: @mjw I just added additional plots (see at the bottom) where I do not use one-hot-encoding and this solution seems accurate to me, so what's wrong with one-hot-encoding? Note that only the decision boundary plots are different

Comment: It looks like the red points do not belong to a simple region.  Aren't the red points divided into two clusters, one separate from the blue points, and one right on top of them?   If this is the case, it's not a simple problem.  I don't know if we agree on this.  Do we?

Comment: What happens when $\lambda$ becomes larger?  What about $\lambda=10$ or $\lambda=100$?  Does it still not have any effect?

Comment: I agree, the red points aren't in one simple region. But that's not my problem. I could easily provide you with an example where I have two clearly separated regions. There you'd see that the decision boundary I calculated as shown in the post is wrong. My problem is that the decision boundary calculation is wrong when I use one-hot-encoding but it is correct when I use an encoding with $\{-1,1\}$. If you'd like, I can show you plots with easier regions/classes. @mjw

Comment: Well, yes, would like that.  The current example is much harder to figure out what the "correct" classification should be.  If you can show an example where your algorithm fails on easier-to-classify, simply linear separated data, that would be better.